# 'synchronize' cell values dependent on each other in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Suppose I have three cells, one containing the distance, one the speed and the other the time. Now I want to be able to fill in two cells (e.g. distance and speed) and have the time calculated in the third cell. But when I fill in the speed and the time, the distance should be calculated.

How can this be achieved in google spreadsheets? I suppose there should be some kind of check to not create an infinite loop. I tried to search for cell synchronization or cell dependency, but I think this is not the right term for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a nested if statement:

```
=if(And(isnumber(A2),isnumber(C2)),ROUND(A2/C2),if(And(isnumber(A2),isnumber(B2)),round(A2/B2),if(and(isnumber(B2),isnumber(C2)),B2*TIMEVALUE(C2)*24,)))
```

Here is a screenshot for all three scenarios:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, +1. But I was looking for a 'three cell solution' where I can calculate results based on the time and speed or distance and speed. Also, speed and time are measured in a duration format, which I think is failing the `isnumber()` check

Comment: @TmKVU I updated the formula to convert the time piece to a timevalue - and as far as your "three cell solution" im not sure what you mean by that , but the only reason I show three rows in the picture was an example, the formula itself handles the variation of all three cases, no matter which cells you fill.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `OnEdit` event:

1. user enters some value (speed, row, distance)
2. script checks for other values,
3. calculates the result
4. paste the result into cells

The whole text of script is here:

```js
function onEdit(t) {
var workSheetName = 'Sheet1'; // change sheet name to yours
var distanceRangeAddress = 'A2:A'; // change if needed
var speedRangeAddress = 'B2:B'; // change if needed
var timeRangeAddress = 'C2:C'; // change if needed

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var sn = ss.getName();

var distance, speed, time;
if (sn == workSheetName) {
  var tr = t.range;
    if (t.oldValue != tr.getValue() && tr.getNumColumns() == 1 && tr.getNumRows() == 1) {
      // distance
      var myr = ss.getRange(distanceRangeAddress);
      if (RangeIntersect(tr, myr)) {
        distance = tr.getValue();
        speed = tr.offset(0, 1).getValue();
        time = tr.offset(0, 2).getValue();
        if (time > 0) {
          speed = distance / time;
          tr.offset(0, 1).setValue(time);
          return;
        }        
        if (speed > 0) {
          time =  distance / speed;
          tr.offset(0, 2).setValue(time);
          return;
        }
      }
      // speed
      myr = ss.getRange(speedRangeAddress);
      if (RangeIntersect(tr, myr)) {     
        speed = tr.getValue();
        distance = tr.offset(0, -1).getValue();
        time = tr.offset(0, 1).getValue();
        if (time > 0) {
          distance = speed * time;
          tr.offset(0, -1).setValue(distance);
          return;
        }        
        if (distance > 0) {
          time =  distance / speed;
          tr.offset(0, 1).setValue(time);
          return;
        }
      } 
      // time
      myr = ss.getRange(timeRangeAddress);
      if (RangeIntersect(tr, myr)) {
        time = tr.getValue();
        distance = tr.offset(0, -2).getValue();
        speed = tr.offset(0, -1).getValue();
        
        if (speed > 0) {
          distance = speed * time;
          tr.offset(0, -2).setValue(distance);
          return;
        }
        if (distance > 0) {
          speed = distance / time;
          tr.offset(0, -1).setValue(speed);
          return;        
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function RangeIntersect(R1, R2) {

  var LR1 = R1.getLastRow();
  var Ro2 = R2.getRow();
  if (LR1 < Ro2) return false;


  var LR2 = R2.getLastRow();
  var Ro1 = R1.getRow();
  if (LR2 < Ro1) return false;

  var LC1 = R1.getLastColumn();
  var C2 = R2.getColumn();
  if (LC1 < C2) return false;

  var LC2 = R2.getLastColumn();
  var C1 = R1.getColumn();
  if (LC2 < C1) return false;

return true;

}
```

You may want to change parametres in the beginning of the script:

```
var workSheetName = 'Sheet1'; // change sheet name to yours
var distanceRangeAddress = 'A2:A'; // change if needed
var speedRangeAddress = 'B2:B'; // change if needed
var timeRangeAddress = 'C2:C'; // change if needed
```

Here's [example file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BqeEOosELmm5NJL-sca1p7_oi9GdQg2nkR7l7CPyqwE/edit?usp=sharing).

The script could be improved and adopted to your needs. Please, look for [more information](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#methods) here.